# Is there a pyarrow array builder

Tags: arrays, builder, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm looking for a python arrow array builder.

My use case is the following: I've got 'row' records that I'd like to convert to an arrow 'columnar' table. For each field in my records I want to create an arrow array of the relevant type. But I don't want to use python arrays as the intermediate representation, as I worry it may be wasteful.

Here's an illustration of my use case:

```
builder = pa.arraybuilder(type=pa.uint32(), capacity_hint=3)
builder.add(1)
builder.add(None)
builder.add(2)
results = builder.build() # type: pa.array
```

Comment: There is not yet, but we have discussed it at times. I didn't find a JIRA issue about it immediately so I opened one https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3917